# R sub- removing line terminators

Tags: r, web-scraping, substring

I'm trying to retrieve information like Depth and Width from a segment of code I've scraped and am having trouble doing it.

```
obtain_url <- html(# Some url)
test <-  obtain_url %>% html_node("#specifications") %>% html_text()
edit(test)


Dimensions:\n                            \n                                    Width (in.):\n                                    30\n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                    Depth (in.):\n                                    24.25\n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                    Width:\n                                    30 inches\n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                    Weight (lbs.):\n                                    320\n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                    Height (in.):\n                                    50.5\n 

dn<-sub(".*Width (in.):\n(.*)\n .*","\\1",test) # My attempt at retrieving width info
```

My attempt just simply spits back out the same text. All the information I'm interested in always appears in the same pattern `Info:\n #36 blank spaces# Information\n`. Sometimes it's a number, sometimes it's just regular text. If someone could just help me retrieve, for example, the numerical value for Width and Depth, I could apply it to everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try `strsplit` for this.

```
clean <- function(x) {
  s <- strsplit(x, '\\n')
  s2 <- gsub('\\s{2,}', '', s[[1]])
  indx <- grep(':', s2)
  paste(s2[indx], s2[indx+1])
}

clean(x)
[1] "Dimensions: "       "Width (in.): 30"    "Depth (in.): 24.25"
[4] "Width: 30 inches"   "Weight (lbs.): 320" "Height (in.): 50.5"
```

If you don't need the text, try this instead:

```
clean2 <- function(x, measure) {
  s <- strsplit(x, '\\n')
  s2 <- gsub('\\s{2,}', '', s[[1]])
  indx <- grep(':', s2)
  res <- s2[indx+1]
  num <- as.numeric(gsub('[^0-9\\.]', '', res, perl=T))
  num
}

clean2(x)
[1]     NA  30.00  24.25  30.00 320.00  50.50
```

Or even better in my opinion:

```
clean3 <- function(x, measure) {
s <- strsplit(x, '\\n')
s2 <- gsub('\\s{2,}', '', s[[1]])
indx <- grep(':', s2)
res <- s2[indx+1]
num <- as.numeric(gsub('[^0-9\\.]', '', res, perl=T))
df <- data.frame(Measure=s2[indx], Value=num)
df
}

# clean3(x)
#          Measure  Value
# 1    Dimensions:     NA
# 2   Width (in.):  30.00
# 3   Depth (in.):  24.25
# 4         Width:  30.00
# 5 Weight (lbs.): 320.00
# 6  Height (in.):  50.50
```

Comment: Clean code. Would be very helpful if you could also show a way to extract specific data only as my question calls for. For example, just the numerical value for Height or Weight. Or if there were strings instead of numbers.

Comment: Check the update. If NAs are not ok for the parts without numbers, it can be changed to another value.

Comment: Fantastic. Looks great. I'll ask you what I asked someone else up above. How do I handle strings? For example, lets say one of the "Measure" input was "Gas or Electric:" and the value was "Gas." Similarly if it was "Clock Type:" and the value was "Digital." I get that numbers are easier to handle but I'd like to be able to do the same thing for strings as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
text <- "Dimensions:\n                            \n                                    Width (in.):\n                                    30\n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                    Depth (in.):\n                                    24.25\n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                    Width:\n                                    30 inches\n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                    Weight (lbs.):\n                                    320\n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                    Height (in.):\n                                    50.5\n "

no_spaces <- gsub("\\n|\\s","",text)

width <- as.numeric(sub(".+Width\\(in\\.\\)\\:(\\d+\\.?\\d?).*",("\\1"),no_spaces)) #30
depth <- as.numeric(sub(".+Depth\\(in\\.\\)\\:(\\d+\\.?\\d?).*",("\\1"),no_spaces)) #24.2
```

The regexes are kind of a pain because you have to quote the parentheses, periods for abbreviations, optional decimal points, etc.  But it seems to work.  HTH

Comment: I'm new to R so it'd be greatly helpful if you could kinda walk me through your solution. Like what does the + and all those backslashes mean. I'd really like to understand it.

Comment: Most of what you may be unfamiliar with is not specific to R but to regular expressions.  http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html  For example `+` assertion means "one or more".  The ` \\ ` is kind of an R-ism because R treats it as ` \ ` which is a quote in regex.  If you didn't quote the period it would mean "any character" and if you didn't quote the parentheses it would mean a grouping operation such as I use to capture the numeric content...

Comment: ..the numeric content is captured by `(\\d\\.?\\d?)` which R reads as `(\d\.?\d?)` which in regex means "numbers followed by optional decimal point followed by optional numbers" and is returned by `\\1` which means the 1st captured group (in this case the only group).

Comment: Also Width and Depth were kind of exclusive cases as they were followed by `(in.):` and contained digits. How do I adapt this to include just regular strings? For example if my code contains, `Clock Type:\n                  Digital\n` and I want to retrieve "Digital"?

Comment: If you are capturing strings your approach would be slightly different.  You might not want to remove spaces ahead of time, you would detect `Clock Type` instead of `(in.)` and look for letters after that instead of digits.  You might find the word boundary assertion `\b` helpful.  If you are looking at a lot of data in name-value pairs you might want to think of a standard way to catch all of those instead of writing a bunch of different regexes.

Comment: Would word boundary assertion help me capture every word within the `\n` and the closing `\n`? I'm finding that to be the challenging part. I would like to capture any and every word within the line terminating tags but I just don't know the syntax for it. Any example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81677/discussion-between-sammy-and-c8h10n4o2).